# Symfony - I have a problem with ParamConverter without my touching my code for several days

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, controller, annotations, router

I installed PHPUnit in my project and I came back to my url where there was an id and it gave me an error that I didn't have before : "App\Entity\Recipe object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation."

So, I put a @ParamConverter in annotation so that it does not make me any more errors:

```php
/**
     * @Route("/api/recipes/{id}", name="recipeGetID", methods={"GET"})
     * @ParamConverter ("recipe", class="Recipe")
     */
    public function GetID(Recipe $recipe, $id): Response
    {
        // We specify that we use the JSON encoder
        $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];

        // We instantiate the "normalizer" to convert the collection into an array
        $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

        // We instantiate the converter
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        // We convert to json
        $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($recipe, 'json', [
            'circular_reference_handler' => function ($object) {
                return $object->getId();
            }
        ]);

        $response = new Response($jsonContent);

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
```

But it puts me : "App\Entity\Recipe object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation."

So I followed it but without success: https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#usage

Do you have any idea how to fix it? (I have been working on the project for 3 days and it is only now that the bug appears)

Comment: Remove the `$id` argument from your `GetID` controller method. It is unused and conflicts with the `Recipe $recipe` specification, which the `ParamConverter` will automatically translate as `$em:->find(Recipe::class, $id)`, without needing to manually declare `@ParamConverter`. Otherwise you are wanting `@Entity("recipe", expr="repository.find(id)")`

Comment: Thanks you so much !